# Windows Forms: Progress Bar in a DataGridView column

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, progress-bar

How can I show progressbars in the cells of a winforms datagridview column?

Comment: please check this link hope this will help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090691/add-progress-bar-in-gridview-using-datatable-or-dataset-in-window-application

Answer (score 1):

maybe help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol(VS.80).aspx