# Set background color for some text in DataGridViewCell

Tags: .net, winforms, forms, datagridview

I know a way to change the background color of a cell in a DataGridView:

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color
```

However, I need to change the background color for only a portion of the text.

For instance, if I have "Harry meets Sally" in a cell, I would like to set "Harry" in pink background and "Sally" in a green background.

Does anyone know of a good way to do that?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with the standard tools avalible. You will have to override the paint event of a custom class that inherits from a `DataGridViewImageCell`. An example of how to do this is provided as part of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100992/626442 which shows how to create a progress bar inside a `DataGridViewCell`. Using this answer, extending it to what you require should not be too tasking.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains("Harry") == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Pink;
        }
        else if(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains("Sally") == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
```

Comment: Err, no. Not what I asked. And you might wanna avoid going the "if (condition == true)" way.